# Swift SpriteKit: Incorrect sprite position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've created a new Xcode game project and selected SpriteKit. By default, Xcode provides a game template which I modified to add image. The image was displayed on the screen but in incorrect position. I followed [this](http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions) tutorial to setup the correct scene dimension and it works. But the image is still in incorrect position.

I'm trying to position the image at Y=0, but it appears at the bottom of the screen instead of the top.

[image]

Here's what I've done so far.

ViewController Code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();

    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    println(skView)

    let scale:CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
    let size = CGSizeMake(skView.frame.size.width*scale, skView.frame.size.height*scale)

    if (skView.scene == nil) {

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene    {
            // Configure the view.
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.size = size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
    else {
        skView.scene!.size = size;
    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}
}
```

Scene Code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    println(self)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 31.0/255.0, green: 31.0/255.0, blue: 31.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    //Add the app logo
    let logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"imgLogo")
    logo.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y:0)
    self.addChild(logo)

    let lblTitle = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"LibelSuit-Regular")
    lblTitle.text = "Hello World!";
    lblTitle.fontSize = 65;
    lblTitle.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    self.addChild(lblTitle)
}
}
```

Comment: This is *all* covered in Apple's documentenation on [Building a Scene in Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html),  under 'Creating a Scene'.

Comment: So this is the expected behavior then. Thanks for the info @ABakerSmith.

Comment: Indeed, it's a bit confusing coming from UIKit, but you'll soon get used to it. Or, you could change the `anchorPoint` of the scene...

Answer (score 0):

I assume logo is the red/green boxes on the bottom? If so, y = 0 is the bottom edge, not the top. Try:

```
logo.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, 
                        y:self.frame.size.height - logo.size.height / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike game development for other platforms, the y-axis in spritekit runs from down to up instead of up to down. In this case you'd want to replace the 0 with self.frame.size.height

```
logo.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y:0) //Your current code
logo.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y:self.frame.size.height)//What you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Scene anchor point was set to (0,0) - lower left of the screen by default, what I did is to set the anchor point to (0,1) - upper  left instead.

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
```

I also set the same anchor point for each child, then I set the Y position to a negative value.

```
let logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"imgLogo")
logo.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
logo.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:-180)
self.addChild(logo)
```

This works perfectly. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Are you not better off adapting to SKScene's default anchor point? Changing it might confuse anyone looking at your code, plus you have to always adapt and examples you;re trying to follow. Also, other nodes are best left with their anchor in the middle, for rotation etc. Moving it can also affect physiocsBodies.

Answer (score 0):

Why would y = 0 be at the top? Just think of it as a graph like the ones you've learned in school. y = 0 is in the bottom and x = 0 is on the left side. So 0,0 would be on the left bottom corner.

Comment: In UIKit on iOS, y is at the top, so most iOS developers are used to this orientation.